# How to import class from npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I created a npm package, the package just export a simple class, and I want to create an instance of that class in my code. but I want to be able access the class directly:

**The package:**

```
export class SomeClass{
  ///
}
```

**My code now:**

```
var SomeClass = require('some-class').SomeClass
var obj = new SomeClass()
```

**How I want it to be:**

```
var SomeClass = require('some-class')
var obj = new SomeClass()
```

Is it possible to export it in a way that will make it work?

Comment: You could `const { SomeClass } = require('some-class')`. You are mixing ES6 export with CommonJS require. That's not a problem but probably difficult to do for a beginner.

Comment: Use export default: `class SomeClass{}; export default SomeClass`